# Recognize the interrupt every time a folder is double clicked and pass the info to nodejs inorder to generate an otp.

Tags: python, node.js, linux, operating-system

I am working on a project to generate an otp every time a folder is to be accessed and send the otp to the owner of the system.

Unable to find out how to Catch the interrupt originated to access the folder.

Comfortable with both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Lots of things here not clear to me:  What does "recognize the interrupt mean"?  What is an "otp"?  Why is this tagged with both python and node.js?  Are you trying to "recognize the click" on windows or linux or both?  Is this question more about recognizing a click?  Or about sending data to a node.js app?  What app is the click happening in?

Comment: Sir actually I just want to recognise the click after which I want to generate a random one time password -pass it on to nodejs and then send it to the owner's phone and once the one time password is entered the folder can be accessed.

Comment: Project has no specified operating system to work on ...So I can use either of the two .